# How to export datagridview data to an other datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm import SQL into Datagridview1 and i wanna export Datagridview1 data it into an other Datagridview2.

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet("Recordset")
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter


    cn.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" & _
            "SERVER=server_name;" & _
            "DATABASE=databas_name;" & _
            "User Id=ID;" & _
            "PWD=PWD;" & _
            "Option="

    Try
        cn.Open()
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        da.Fill(ds, rs, "example")

        rs.Open("select * " & _
                "from bom " & _
                cn, _
                ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, _
                ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic _
                )

        da.Fill(ds, rs, "example")
        Form2.DataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView

        MsgBox("SQL import kész!")

        cn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
```

There is the code to import in sql, but i dont know how can i export it to an other, Datagridview.
Thanks the help.

Comment: Why do you use the old `ADODB.Recordset` in VB.NET? What database are you using? Why can't you simply use the same DataSource for both grids, so `ds.Tables(0)`?

Comment: My database name is "bom". I learned this way to work with sql.
My problem is, i wanna work with the datagridview data into an other datagridview with a new select, without sql conncetion.
Can u example it?!

Answer (score 0):

declare a datatable, read data from both gridview row wise and add to the datatable. in last bind this datatable to gridview you want